# pulseaudio network stream disconnects

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, raspberry-pi, pulseaudio, streaming

I set up a pulseaudio network stream (wlan) to my raspberry pi. Therefore, after testing multiple tutorials on how to set up a audio stream via network, I succeeded with the following partly:
Pulseaudio is running as a service with a the service-file `/etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio.service` containing

```
[Unit]    
Description=PulseAudio system server
[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --system --realtime --log-target=journal --disallow-exit --disallow-module-loading --log-level=1 --exit-idle-time=-1
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The host is a Ubuntu machine (4.4.0-116-generic) with `paprefs` installed and configured. In the configuration (raspberry pi) of pulseaudio in both `/etc/pulse/system.pa` and `/etc/pulse/default.pa` I appended

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;X.X.X.X/24
load-module module-zeroconf-publish
```

with `X.X.X.X`  replaced by the hosts IP adress. When I start the service on the Pi via

```
sudo systemctl --system restart pulseaudio.service
```

or

```
sudo systemctl --system restart pulseaudio.service
```

on the host there appears the new output sink and audio is piped correctly (videos in the browser have a small desynchronisation) to the pi. But after a randomly gambled time, the connection is lost, meaning the audio stream on the pi stops and the service terminates.
I sense in a way that the wlan connection could be a problem, but on the other site, if everything is running, it's running correctly. So the network connection should be good enough. Additionally pulseaudio sometimes tells itself, that it is a bad idea to run it in system wide mode, the same error occures for user-only mode .
What can I do about this disconnects?

edit:
When the service terminates `sudo systemctl --system status pulseaudio.service` tells

```
● pulseaudio.service - PulseAudio system server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio.service; enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fr 2018-03-16 20:51:21 CET; 125ms ago
Process: 6181 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --system --realtime --log-target=journal --disallow-exit --disallow-module-loading --log-level=1 --exit-idle-time=-1 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 6181 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mär 16 20:49:51 raspberrypi pulseaudio[6181]: Host part of ACL entry 'X.X.X.X/24' is not zero!
Mär 16 20:49:52 raspberrypi pulseaudio[6181]: Denied access to client with invalid authorization data.
Mär 16 20:51:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: pulseaudio.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Mär 16 20:51:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: pulseaudio.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mär 16 20:51:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start PulseAudio system server.
Mär 16 20:51:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit pulseaudio.service entered failed state.
```

`/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/daemon.log` tell the same:

[syslog](http://textuploader.com/dgj1x)

[daemon.log](http://textuploader.com/dgj12)

Unfortunately, `journalctl -a` tells that there are no journal files.

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: I appended the logs.

Comment: Does the connection break while streaming or only when idle?

Comment: Also check if this subnet: `X.X.X.X/24` does indeed have the zero for hosts, ie. it is `X.X.X.0/24`.

Comment: The disconnects happens while streaming and while idle. `ifconfig` for the `wlan0` connection shows  the line `inet address :192.168.178.20  Bcast:192.168.178.255  mask:255.255.255.0`.
How does this affect the pulseaudio stream?

Comment: See if this line is the same: `load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.178.0/24`. Just checking the configs, after all that's what the error is about: `Host part of ACL entry 'X.X.X.X/24' is not zero!`

Comment: `X.X.X.X` is in every case `192.168.178.20` which is the host (audio source, notebook) in my home network. What makes me wonder, is that `zero` is spelled out and not simply a numeric `0`. Is it somehow needed to have a host-IP address ending with a zero?

Comment: You give the /24 mask, so it should be 0.

Comment: Since I am completly new to subnetting, what should I do about this?

Comment: Try `load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.178.0/24` and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks! I tried out your suggestions, but still lose the connection. If this is a problem of connectivity, is there an option to make the networkstream more stable, like exist for other network applications?

Comment: Check the log and add to your question. Possibly a longer one. You should be able to get it with `journalctl -e` and scroll up.